# "failed to find data source: json" when running scala assembly fat jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

I have a scala-spark project and I have created a fat jar using sbt assembly. An error raised when I tried to run jar, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: json. Please find packages at [http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html"](http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html%22). I added this code block to build.sbt;

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case  "META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first

}
```

It did not work, I would be very grateful for any help

Best regards

Comment: I am facing similar issue. It works fine when I execute it from IDE (IntelliJ) but when I create a fat jar and run app using command line, I get this exception.